# start game from the screen where user quit last time

Tags: python, pygame

hello guys i need you help
i am working on a game project in pygame(python)
my game has multiple levels and for each level i make a separate file

here is the code of my game

```
from button import *
from level1 import main1
from level2 import main2
from level3 import main3
from level4 import main4
from level5 import main5
from level6 import main6
from level7 import main7
from level8 import main8
from level9 import main9
from level10 import main10
from level11 import main11
from level12 import main12
import pygame
import sys

pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.init()

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
pygame.display.set_caption("Menu")
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 100)


def level():
    pygame.display.set_caption("Levels")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while True:
        OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        SCREEN.fill((3, 54, 73))
        level1 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(320, 60), text_input="LEVEL 1",
                        base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                        music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level1.color = level1.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level1.update(SCREEN)
        level2 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(320, 160), text_input="LEVEL 2",
                        base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                        music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level2.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level2.update(SCREEN)
        level3 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(320, 260), text_input="LEVEL 3",
                        base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                        music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level3.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level3.update(SCREEN)
        level4 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(320, 360), text_input="LEVEL 4",
                        base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                        music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level4.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level4.update(SCREEN)
        level5 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(320, 460), text_input="LEVEL 5",
                        base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                        music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level5.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level5.update(SCREEN)
        level6 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(320, 560), text_input="LEVEL 6",
                        base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                        music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level6.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level6.update(SCREEN)
        level7 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(960, 60), text_input="LEVEL 7",
                        base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                        music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level7.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level7.update(SCREEN)
        level8 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(960, 160), text_input="LEVEL 8",
                        base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                        music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level8.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level8.update(SCREEN)
        level9 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(960, 260), text_input="LEVEL 9",
                        base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                        music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level9.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level9.update(SCREEN)
        level10 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(960, 360), text_input="LEVEL 10",
                         base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                         music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level10.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level10.update(SCREEN)
        level11 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(960, 460), text_input="LEVEL 11",
                         base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                         music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level11.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level11.update(SCREEN)
        level12 = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(960, 560), text_input="LEVEL 12",
                         base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                         music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        level12.changeColor(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS)
        level12.update(SCREEN)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                main_menu()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if level1.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main1()
                if level2.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main2()
                if level3.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main3()
                if level4.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main4()
                if level5.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main5()
                if level6.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main6()
                if level7.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main7()
                if level8.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main8()
                if level9.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main9()
                if level10.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main10()
                if level11.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main11()
                if level12.checkForInput(OPTIONS_MOUSE_POS):
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                    main12()
        pygame.display.update()


def main_menu():
    pygame.display.set_caption("Menu")
    SCREEN.fill((3, 54, 73))
    while True:
        MENU_MOUSE_POS = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        MENU_TEXT = FONT.render("MAIN MENU", True, (0, 204, 0))
        MENU_RECT = MENU_TEXT.get_rect(center=(640, 100))
        PLAY_BUTTON = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(640, 250), text_input="PLAY",
                             base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                             music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        LEVELS = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(640, 400), text_input="LEVELS", base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                        music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        QUIT_BUTTON = Button(image=pygame.image.load("button.png"), font=pygame.font.SysFont("Roboto", 60), pos=(640, 550), text_input="QUIT",
                             base_color="white", hovering_color=(0, 204, 0),
                             music=pygame.mixer.music.load("click sound.wav"))
        SCREEN.blit(MENU_TEXT, MENU_RECT)
        for button in [PLAY_BUTTON, LEVELS, QUIT_BUTTON]:
            button.changeColor(MENU_MOUSE_POS)
            button.update(SCREEN)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if PLAY_BUTTON.checkForInput(MENU_MOUSE_POS):
                    main1()
                if LEVELS.checkForInput(MENU_MOUSE_POS):
                    level()
                if QUIT_BUTTON.checkForInput(MENU_MOUSE_POS):
                    quit()
        pygame.display.update()
```

in this code i have main menu screen in which i have play button on clicking play button level 1 start. as you can see in above import statements each level has separate main function for level1 its main1 and for level2 its main2.

now problem is this when i click on play button level1 starts after completing level1, level2 starts and so on.

but when i quit the game on any level (for example on level4). the game start again from level1.

so what changes i need to do in above code that if i quit on level4 than after clicking play button again next time game continues from level4 and not from level1.

please help

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you need to have a database and need to save user status there and every time you open game first get user status so that you can have the current level of user but there now you should also make reset button too so that user can restart game if he wants you can have database documentations. i usually prefer NoSQL database but you can go for any of them

you can get reference here [https://www.mongodb.com/languages/python#:~:text=The%20first%20step%20to%20connect,text%20editor%20like%20Textpad%2FNotepad.&text=Use%20the%20connection_string%20to%20create,get%20the%20MongoDB%20database%20connection](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/python#:%7E:text=The%20first%20step%20to%20connect,text%20editor%20like%20Textpad%2FNotepad.&text=Use%20the%20connection_string%20to%20create,get%20the%20MongoDB%20database%20connection).

Comment: but i dont know how to save user status. i was working only on python. but mentioned functionality is the demand of my project supervisor. thats why i am asking here for help